# I'm trying to read an excel file from external storage using apache POI and having trouble

Tags: android, apache-poi, storage, file-access, xlsm

I want to parse an excel file in "external storage" with apache POI on an android phone. I put the file in the downloads folder when I downloaded it. I can always expect it to be there, not on a cloud, not being edited by other apps, not ephemeral in any way.  The Apache POI workbookfactory needs a FileInputStream.  After trying many different things I am burnt out.

Other similar questions on here involve huge swaths of code that deal in images and fanciful sources. All the examples I find use startActivityForResult which is DEPRECATED. So I tried some registerForActivityResult using contracts. No dice. Anyone know why the mime type "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12" doesn't work for xlsm files but images/png does? I also tried copying the file from content URI to local/app/scoped/cachedir storage and I wasn't successful either.

I was expecting the ability to point to a file and say "into the Apache POI excel file wood chipper with you!" and like in Fargo the Apache POI would spit little red cell values all over Log.d and eventually I'll do stuff with that information.

```
import android.content.ContentResolver
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor
import android.provider.OpenableColumns
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory
import java.io.*
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel


fun readingxl(input: InputStream?) {

    //Workbook wb = Workbookfactory.create(new File(bob.getPath()))
    //Log.d("wtf",bob.toString())
    //val input = FileInputStream("./text.xlsm")
    //val xlWb = WorkbookFactory.create(input)
    //val input = FileInputStream(bob.getPath())

    val xlWb = WorkbookFactory.create(input)
    Log.d("wtf","b")
    //val xlWb = WorkbookFactory.create(input)
    Log.d("wtf","c")
    val xlWs = xlWb.getSheet("Daily Recording")
    Log.d("wtf","d")

    for (j in 44..50) {


        for (i in 0..11) {
            //Log.d("wtf",((("${xlWs.getRow(j).getCell(i)}, ")).toString()))
            Log.d("wtf", "${xlWs.getRow(j).getCell(i)}, ")

        }

    }
}

fun ContentResolver.getFileName(fileUri: Uri): String {

    var name = ""
    val returnCursor = this.query(fileUri, null, null, null, null)
    if (returnCursor != null) {
        val nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
        returnCursor.moveToFirst()
        name = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex)
        returnCursor.close()
    }

    return name
}


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val getContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
        // 'ActivityResultCallback': Handle the returned Uri
        if (uri != null) {
            Log.d("wtf",uri.getPath().toString())
            val inputStream = applicationContext.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
            readingxl(inputStream)

            /*
            val parcelFileDescriptor = applicationContext.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r", null)

            parcelFileDescriptor?.let {
                val inputStream = FileInputStream(parcelFileDescriptor.fileDescriptor)
                val file = File(applicationContext.cacheDir, "text.xlsm")//applicationContext.contentResolver.getFileName(uri))
                val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
                IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream)
            }*/


            }



        }




    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        ///storage/emulated/0/Download


        var button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)

        button.setOnClickListener{


            //getContent.launch("*/*")
            getContent.launch("*/*")

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of a FileInputStream give it the InputStream you opened for the uri.

Comment: `fun readingxl(input: InputStream?) {` ?? FileInputStream?

Comment: "Anyone know why the mime type "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12" doesn't work for xlsm files" -- Android does not know about every possible MIME type. "I put the file in the downloads folder when I downloaded it" -- you will need to download it from inside your app to be able to access it in `Downloads/` on Android 11+. "I also tried copying the file from content URI to local/app/scoped/cachedir storage and I wasn't successful either" -- your [mcve] does not show this. `FileInputStream("./text.xlsm")` does not refer to a valid path, and we do not know what `bob` is.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Sorry Bob was a temp variable I was using when trying different "solutions" from stackoverflow and the web.

Comment: @CommonsWare the commented out ./text.xlsm was from another attempt to copy the file to local storage.  I was under the impression that using the getcontent with a documents contract allowed the user to select a file for use in the app, since the user is doing the selection it satisfies whatever privacy concern that made this whole process convoluted in the first place?

Comment: "allowed the user to select a file for use in the app" -- it allows the user to select *content* for use in the app. There is no requirement that it be a file on the filesystem, let alone one that your app can access. For the short term, the simplest thing may be to use `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context`. That is a directory unique to your app that you can read from and write to freely. It is not super-convenient for users, but that may or may not be an issue for you, and you can get more comfortable with Android and switch to some other storage option later.

Comment: @blackapps I used the inputstream for workbook factory and I now get an  Caused by: org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader; which I assume means a problem with my POI libs? I can't find a lib for XMLStreamReader though

Comment: Your post is a mess, your code is a mess, you talk about a hundred things. Rewrite. Start with an uri and show how you use it.

Comment: @blackapps wins.  There's a workbookfactory that accepts a regular inputstream instead of a FileInputStream.  Also my other problems invovled POI and android not playing nice.  By the time I found a way to use a version of POI that targeted android my xlsm file caused an out of memory error. I am giving up on POI and I am now resorting to saving my spreadsheet as a csv. Thank you all for your assitance. ETA: I don't know how to mark a comment as answering my question